# Outlook add-in: How to remove (or not include) original email when replying

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Is anyone aware of a way to remove the original message from being included in a reply? I cannot find anything in the documentation or around the web in regards to doing so. Essentially, I want to reply to an email with only the content that I include in the HTML body.

The reply does not appear to be a part of the html content when viewing it in the onSend handler. It must be added after the fact and I'm unable to find a way to not include it.

Edit: I believe the original message is appended by an "appendonsend" function that Microsoft runs after any other item-send function runs.

If I am to change my read settings to show messages individually, this does not appear to run and it works how I would like. But I don't want to require users to move away from grouping messages as conversations as that reduces their productivity.

Comment: Could you clarify the platform you're using? Is this for Outlook on the Web or Win32? The appendOnSend API is not called unless you call it from within the add-in.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT this is definitely happening in Outlook on the web (office.com). When replying to a message (with conversation view enabled), you see the 3 little dots at the bottom (expanding this includes the original message being replied to).

From within our add-in, if we call Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync('html', ...), it does not include the content that is there when you press the three dots. Yet, when we send the message, it is always included (unless the user actually presses the three dots and deletes it).

Comment: So I definitely could be wrong about it being added by an "appendOnSend" call, as I do see it in the body if (and only if) I click the 3 dots at the bottom of the compose window. Without clicking those dots, there appears to be no way to actually remove that content so we can send only the desired content of the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour observered is by design in OWA. body.getAsync API will return the complete text only if '...' button is clicked.

The functionality to remove email body during on send, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](http://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.